# Relative reference subtotal formula in vba

Tags: vba, excel, formula, subtotal

I'm trying to make a table that has subtotals every few columns. My vba code brings and sorts data from another sheet into sections and now i'm trying to write the code to have the subtotal formulas put in. Here is what i have:

```
Sub Macro21()
Dim FI(1 To 3) As Variant
FI(1) = "Fixed Income"
FI(2) = 10
FI(3) = 21

Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(FI(2), 3).FormulaR1C1 = "=SUBTOTAL(9,R[1]C:R[FI(3)-FI(2)]C)"

End Sub
```

FI(2) and FI(3) are the beginning and ending rows for this section. I use them in other parts of the macro and they are updated as new items are put under a category.

When I run this it give me an error. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to *build* the formula as a string, not make it *refer* your `Variant` array. How about:

```
Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(FI(2), 3).FormulaR1C1 = _
     "=SUBTOTAL(9,R[1]C:R[" _
   & CStr(FI(3)-FI(2)) _
   & "]C)"
```

This assuming the resulting string is what you'd like to calculate...

Comment: Your logic makes sense but it still give me an error. On a side note how does one use the _ properly?

Comment: 1) What error? 2) `_` as the last char on a line of code (and preceded by a space) allows continuation of the current statement on the next line of code.

Comment: That is neat. The error says subscript out of range. Sorry, I stepped away for a bit.

Comment: Is the error on the line that calculates the formula? If yes, do you really have a sheet that has the Name `"Sheet1"` (easiest to test is in Immediate window with `?Sheets("Sheet1").Name`).

Comment: That was the problem. I had the wrong sheet name. You are awesome.